# how do i match if value match my dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I'm super new to python so i don't know anything even the basics of basics function so could anyone tell me how do i match value to my dictionary and where did i do wrong

```
#dictionary
id = {"2":"30", "3":"40"}

#json display from web
messages: {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}

if messages['id'] == id:  # << this part i think i'm doing it wrong too because it prints error`
    print ('the new id value from dictionary')  # << what do i put in here`
else:
    print ('error')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if str(messages['id']) in id` instead of `if messages['id'] == id`

Comment: I've changed it to in but for some reason it still prints error and thank you for helping me!^^

Comment: I edited my answer. This new version should work

Answer (score 1):

to check if a values is a key in a dict you can do it like this:

```
if messages['id'] in id:
```

but it will not work right away in your case.
The values in the json data are integers so you need to convert them to match the dict.
you will end up with this

```
if str(messages['id']) in id:
```

full code:

```
id = {"2": "30", "3": "40"}
messages = {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}
if str(messages['id']) in id:
    print(id[str(messages['id'])])
else:
    id[str(messages['id'])] = '50'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! the second one works!!^^.... however, what do i do next if i want to print the new value in the dictionary?

Comment: if you want to add the id to give the dict the new key and value `id[str(messages['id'])] = '50'`

Comment: if i could ask one more thing what do i do if i just want to update the value with the new value from dictionary and prints value not found if doesn't match with the one dictionary? again thank you so much for helping me!^^

Comment: the same as with the other comment, just instead of 50, the new value
Hope the reply isnt to late ^^

Comment: no it's not too late thank you for helping me improving i wish you to have a nice day ahead!!!

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you need to use an `=` to assign variables:

```
messages = {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}
```

instead of

```
messages: {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}
```

---

Concerning what you want to achieve, you are trying to access a dictionary value by using a default value (`"error"`) in case the key doesn't exist. You can use `dict.get` for that, rather than `if-else`:

```
#dictionary
id_dict = {"2":"30", "3":"40"}

#json display from web
messages = {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}
    
print(id_dict.get(messages['id'], "error"))
```

---

Caveats:

- Don't use `id` as a variable name, as it is a Python built-in keyword.
- If the `id_dict` has string keys, you also need to use strings to access it, i.e. `messages = {"id":2 ...` will not give you the value `"30"` for `id_dict = {"2":"30", "3":"40"}`.

Comment: You need to convert `messages['id']` to string as keys are all string values

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value to check to string in order to perform a valid comparison. Also, you should not use Python keywords as name variables to avoid additional issues:

```
id_dict = {"2":"30", "3":"40"}

#Use = to assign variables, not :
messages = {"id":2,"class":0,"type":1,"member":"N"}

if str(messages['id']) in id_dict:
    print ('the new id value from dictionary') 
else:
    print ('error')
```

**Output:**

```
the new id value from dictionary
```